# Pine Script How to add title to conditional colors

Tags: pine-script

```
plot(close, "Close", close > EMA200 ? color.green : color.red)
```

How do I add titles for the colors used if I'm using conditional colors like the code above?

[image]

On the Style tab, it just displays the colors as Color 0 and Color 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you can directly (at least I don't remember seeing an example of named colours on the Styles tab).

You can put conditional colour settings on the Inputs tab, eg:

```
col_macd = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="MACD")
col_signal = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="Signal")
```

(the example taken from the built-in MACD indicator)

[image: Built-in macd filter showing named colours in the Inputs tab]